# IOS : com.facebook.sdk error 5

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

Am using the last Facebook SDK for IOS but I always get this error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)  Please do you have any idea about that ?
Thank You.

```
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",user.name);
        //self.emailLabel.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Could you please provide the relevant code that causes this error? Without this, it's rather hard to tell what is wrong. For more information on what should be included in questions, see [ask].

Comment: This part of code :
[[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",user.name);
                    //self.emailLabel.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
                }
                else{
                    NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
                }
            }];

Comment: I have solved this issue by doing this :

[FBSession setActiveSession:session];

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this kind of issue by doing this :

`[FBSession setActiveSession:session];`

Thank you !

Comment: Hello Sean Dev ! I know maybe it's too late but I prefere to anwser your question : I think I did it in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method (AppDelegate). Hope this help !

Answer (score 1):

add the following code in  AppDelegate File.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBAppEvents activateApp];
    [FBAppCall handleDidBecomeActive];
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO];
}
```

The graph API calls used to work when I used to do the login & then make any calls.
But when I used to re-open the app, the graph API call to get the photos used to fail with error code 5.
So, after looking into FBSession class, I found that [FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]; call would make the session active. And thus the issue got fixed.