# iOS Facebook SDK Error Code 5 getting user Information

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm trying to do the raw basics to get user credentials for Facebook. Here is my code:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"] allowLoginUI:NO
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

     [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
     if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen){
        //Success

       [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error){
                 if (!error) {
                     // Success! Include your code to handle the results here
                     NSLog(@"user info: %@", result);
                 } else {
                     // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                     // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                 }
             }];
     }
     else{
         //Prompt for login
     }
 }];
```

Whenever I reach `FBRequestConnection` completion hander, I get error code 5.  I have tried the solution here, but no luck: [IOS : com.facebook.sdk error 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520195/ios-com-facebook-sdk-error-5).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Turns out you need internet access on your phone to access Facebook. **Facepalm**